FFmpeg can successfully retrieve the RTSP stream, but it cannot print the time_base
I can successfully obtain the RTSP stream and use the av_dump_format function to print the stream information, but I cannot retrieve the time_base. Why is that?
FFmpeg is version: n4.0.6
this is my code:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval systemstart_time;
    struct timeval rtspfetch_time1;
    struct timeval rtspfetch_time2;

    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    AVPacket *av_packet = NULL;
    AVDictionary *options = NULL;

    gettimeofday(&systemstart_time, NULL);
    print_time_with_microseconds(systemstart_time);
    //av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    const char *input_url = "rtsp://admin:Read1234@192.168.1.164:554/Streaming/channels/1";
    av_dict_set(&options, "buffer_size", "1024000", 0); 
    av_dict_set(&options, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0); 
    av_dict_set(&options, "stimeout", "5000000", 0); 
    av_dict_set(&options, "max_delay", "500000", 0); 

    pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context(); 
    printf("FFmpeg version1: %s\n", av_version_info());  
    //Open Rtsp Streaming
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, input_url, NULL, &options) != 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open input stream.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    gettimeofday(&rtspfetch_time1, NULL);
    print_time_with_microseconds(rtspfetch_time1);
    //Get Stream information
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't find stream information.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    gettimeofday(&rtspfetch_time2, NULL);
    print_time_with_microseconds(rtspfetch_time2);
    //Find if there is a video stream in the stream
    int videoindex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            AVRational time_base = pFormatCtx->streams[i]->time_base;
            mpp_log("time_base: %d/%d\n", time_base.num, time_base.den);
            videoindex = i;
            //break;
        } else {
            printf("Didn't find a video stream.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, input_url, 0);  
}

result:
the time_base in pFormatCtx->streams[i] is 0;
time_base:0/0
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:Read1234@192.168.1.164:554/Streaming/channels/1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.240000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc



Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
